# Campos más largos

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

tengo este formulario que esta diseñado con bootstrap 4.3.1, hasta ahora no me había percatado de este problema por que no había usado inputs-group con iconos.

El problema es que cuando hago uso de las clases para tener campos con iconos, hay campos que se vuelven más pequeños que los otros y no se ve estetico. He estado buscando la solución por hora pero no he podido hayar el problema, así que he acudido aquí y espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracías.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-0pzryjIRos8mFBWMzSSZApWtPl/5++eIfzYmTgBBmXYdhvxPc+XcFEk+zJwDgWbP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group row">
            <label for="cmbPreval" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Prevalidador:</label>
            <select name="cmbPreval" id="cmbPreval" class="col-md-8 custom-select">
                <option value="40">prueba</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group row">
            <label for="txtFechaInicio" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Del:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
                <input type="text" id="txtFechaInicio" name="txtFechaInicio" class="form-control" data-link-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group row">
            <label for="txtFechaFin" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Al:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
                <input type="text" id="txtFechaFin" name="txtFechaFin" class="form-control" data-link-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group row">
            <label for="txtRSCliente" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Buscar:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtRSCliente" name="txtRSCliente" class="form-control col-md-8">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group row">
            <label for="cmbEmpresa" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Buscar:</label>
            <input type="text" id="cmbEmpresa" name="cmbEmpresa" class="form-control col-md-8">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group row">
            <label for="txtRSCliente1" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Buscar:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtRSCliente1" name="txtRSCliente1" class="form-control col-md-8">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he arreglado, resulta ser que las clases input-group y form-group se añaden al mismo div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-0pzryjIRos8mFBWMzSSZApWtPl/5++eIfzYmTgBBmXYdhvxPc+XcFEk+zJwDgWbP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group row">
            <label for="cmbPreval" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Prevalidador:</label>
            <select name="cmbPreval" id="cmbPreval" class="col-md-8 custom-select">
                <option value="40">prueba</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group input-group row">
            <label for="txtFechaInicio" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Del:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtFechaInicio" name="txtFechaInicio" class="col-md-8 form-control" data-link-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group input-group row">
            <label for="txtFechaInicio" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Al:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtFechaFin" name="txtFechaFin" class="col-md-8 form-control" data-link-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group row">
            <label for="txtRSCliente" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Buscar:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtRSCliente" name="txtRSCliente" class="form-control col-md-8">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group row">
            <label for="cmbEmpresa" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Buscar:</label>
            <input type="text" id="cmbEmpresa" name="cmbEmpresa" class="form-control col-md-8">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group row">
            <label for="txtRSCliente1" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Buscar:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtRSCliente1" name="txtRSCliente1" class="form-control col-md-8">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```